# dotenv : how to set custom path

Tags: reactjs, dotenv

This is my architecture and I want to access the.env file

I tried all the solutions, __dirname, find-config, ckey and read all the stack solutions. I can't understand why my .env file is not loaded....

[image]

console output is always :

```
{NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: ""}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `create-react-app` to bootstrap your application, the `react-scripts` module handles setting up environment variables for you. However, there's a catch. All React environment variable needs to be prefixed with `REACT_APP`. Thus, your environment variable would be: `REACT_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE`.

You should not import `dotenv`. After changing `.env` files, you must restart the development server. This is the excerpt from the `create-react-app` docs. **The `.env` must appear in the root of your project.**

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with
>   REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to
>   avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could
>   have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require
>   you to restart the development server if it is running.

You can read more about environment variables and `.env` files with `create-react-app` in the [create-react-app documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env).

Comment: Solved. Thank you a lot !!! spent more than 3 hours on it.
I removed require(dotenv) and restarted my app...

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to set a custom path, you can use [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd). It requires small changes in scripts section like this:

```json
// from
"start": "react-scripts start"
// to
"start": "env-cmd -f ./custom/path/.env react-scripts start"
```